# get() whats the diff?

Tags: oop, processing

Whats the difference between these two?

```
PVector a = new PVector(10,12);
PVector b = a;
```

and

```
PVector a = new PVector(10,12);
PVector b = a.get();
```

I realise get() returns a copy of the pvector, but whats the difference from the other one?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

In your first example, `b` and `a` reference the same instance of `PVector`. Therefore, if you change `a.x` or `a.y`, that change will be reflected in `b` as well.

The second copies the `PVector`. Changes to one won't be reflected in the other as they're separate instances of the object.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is above, just to illustrate...

```java
PVector a = new PVector(10,12);
PVector b = a.get(); 
PVector c = new PVector(10,12);
PVector d = c;

b.x = 5;
b.y = 7;

d.x = 3;
d.y = 6;

println("a = " + a + "\n");

println("c = " + c + "\n");
```